# PreparedStatement of JDBCTemplate throws exception "Before start of result set"

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

i am using **Spring JdbcTemplate**. And i have query to get data by ID.
I have this table schema :

```
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id            | varchar(150) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| position_name | varchar(150) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| description   | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

And i run using this template :

```
public Position fetchById(final String id) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM position WHERE id = ?";

    return jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new PreparedStatementSetter() {
        public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ps.setString(1, id);
        }
    }, new ResultSetExtractor<Position>() {

        public Position extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException,
                DataAccessException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Position p = new Position();
            p.setId(rs.getString("id"));
            p.setPositionName(rs.getString("position_name"));
            p.setDescription(rs.getString("description"));

            return p;
        }
    });
}
```

But when i run unit test like this :

```
@Test
public void getPositionByIdTest() throws Exception {
    String id = "35910510-ef2f-11e5-9ce9-5e5517507c66";
    Position p = positionService.getPositionById(id);

    Assert.assertNotNull(p);
    Assert.assertEquals("Project Manager", p.getPositionName());
}
```

I get this following error :

```
org.springframework.dao.TransientDataAccessResourceException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [SELECT * FROM position WHERE id = ?]; Before start of result set; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:108)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73)
    ...
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:957)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:896)
    ...
```

How to use PreparedStatement in Select query JDBC Template?
Thank you.

Comment: Don't you need to call `rs.next()` to advance to the first row before accessing fields in `rs`?

Comment: Here is i just retrieve one record/one object. And i use that method cause i think fit for my case. But maybe any best fit method to process `select` query with `preparedstatement`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call [`ResultSet#next()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html//) to "move the cursor forward one row from its current position." As you are expecting a single row to be returned from your query, you can call this in an `if` statement as shown below:

```
public Position extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException,
            DataAccessException {
        Position p = new Position();
        if(rs.next()) {
            p.setId(rs.getString("id"));
            p.setPositionName(rs.getString("position_name"));
            p.setDescription(rs.getString("description"));
        }
        return p;
}
```

If you were expecting to process multiple results and return a collection of some sort, you would do `while(rs.next())` and process a row on each iteration of the loop.

Also, as you are using `JdbcTemplate` you could consider using a [`RowMapper`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/RowMapper.html) instead which may simplify your implementation slightly.

Comment: Yeah it works for me. I miss that line code `if (rs.next())`
thank you

Answer (score 3):

You have a simple use case and use one of the more complex query methods, why? Next you are using a `ResultSetExtractor` whereas you probably want a `RowMapper` instead. If you use a `ResultSetExtractor` you will have to iterate over the result set yourself. Replace your code with the following

```
return getJdbcTemplate.query(sql, new RowMapper<Position>() {
    public Position mapRow(ResultSet rs, int row) throws SQLException,
            DataAccessException {
        Position p = new Position();
        p.setId(rs.getString("id"));
        p.setPositionName(rs.getString("position_name"));
        p.setDescription(rs.getString("description"));

        return p;
    }, id);
}
```

So instead of using one of the complexer methods, use one that suits what you need. The `JdbcTemplate` uses a `PreparedStatement` anyway.

Comment: Yep, RowMapper is definitely the better solution.

Comment: I alredy implement your code and i must return data as a `List` and i just want to return as a single object `Position`

Comment: Replace `query` with `queryForObject`... I suggest a read of the documentation...

Answer (score 1):

If you use a `ResultSetExtractor` you must iterate through the result for using `next()` calls. This explains the error since the `ResultSet` is still positioned before the first row, when you read its values.

For your use case - to select a record for a given id - there is a simpler solution using `JdbcTemplate.queryForObject` and a `RowMapper` lambda:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM position WHERE id = ?";
Position position = (Position) jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
    sql, new Object[] { id }, (ResultSet rs, int rowNum)  -> {
        Position p = new Position();
        p.setId(rs.getString("id"));
        p.setPositionName(rs.getString("position_name"));
        p.setDescription(rs.getString("description"));
       r eturn p;
    });
```